# What is the range of the Heavy's taunt kill?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-heavy

I've seen videos where players kill others with the taunt kill from a couple meters away , kill others from on top of them, to killing them below them.

Ex 1:
Player A = Heavy
Player B = Enemy Player

```
A-->________B
Results in kill.

     __B______
     |        |
     |        |
A-->_|________|
Results in kill


A-->B
Results in kill.
```

So what exactly is the range of the heavy's taunt kill?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Community testing has found that the range at which this taunt will
>   kill is actually pretty respectable for such a situational attack. The
>   taunt can and will kill people who are **standing the equivalent of 9
>   players away**, of any class, from the Heavy performing the taunt in a
>   horizontal line, or **about the length of one of the storage units at
>   Granary**. The taunt's vertical range is approximately the distance
>   between the ground level and second floor ceiling of 2Fort.

Source: [Community Wiki page](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Showdown)